# The integral symbol is shorter compared to the integral symbols that follow in the rest of the document. Why?

Tags: align, arrays, integral

This is the code that gives me shorter integral symbol

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{l}
{a_0} = \dfrac{1}{2L}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} {f\left( x \right)dx} \\
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
{a_n} = \dfrac{1}{L}\int\limits_{-L}^{L} {f(x)\cos \left( {\dfrac{n\pi}{L}x} \right)dx}\\
{b_n} = \dfrac{1}{L}\int\limits_{ - L}^L {f(x)\sin \left( {\dfrac{n\pi}{L}x} \right)dx}
\end{array}
\right\},n = \{1,2,3,...,N\}
\end{array}
\end{align*}
```

[image: Shorter integral symbol]

This is the code that gives me a taller integral symbol

```
\[
{a_1} = \dfrac{1}{\pi }\int\limits_{ - \pi }^\pi  
  {f\left( x \right)\cos \left( {\dfrac{{1\cdot\pi }}{\pi }x} \right)} dx
\]
```

[image: Taller integral symbol]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SC! This is because inside an array (or a matrix, or a cases) environment, you're in `\textstyle`. Simply add `\displaystyle`.

Comment: Also note it would be simple to use the `rcases` environment from `mathtools` than `\left.\begin{array}{l}...\end{array}\right\}`.

Comment: the fact that you are needing to use `\dfrac` is a sign that things are wrong `array` is meant for matrices and arrays of values, not displayed equations, the amsmath alignments use displaystyle math

Comment: Unfortunately, amsmath "cases" is a simple invocation of "array", so has textstyle.

Comment: You appear to have included `3,...,N` in your code. The result will look different, and better, if instead you type `3,\ldots,N`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a setup that doesn't require you to insert a plethora of `\dfrac` and `\limits` directives -- while still getting you the desired, i.e., large integral symbol. As a bonus, it also performs alignment on the `=` symbols -- which isn't the case in your code but nevertheless seems desirable from a typographical point of view.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
\usepackage{mleftright} \mleftright % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a_0 &= \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\,dx \\
a_n &= \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x)\cos 
       \left( \frac{n\pi}{L} x \right)\,dx, 
       \quad n = 1,2,\dots,N \\
b_n &= \frac{1}{L} \int_{ - L}^L f(x)\sin 
       \left( \frac{n\pi}{L} x \right)\,dx,
       \quad n = 1,2,\dots,N
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

Observe how much the input code has been simplified. Take, for instance, the first row, which has been simplified from

```
{a_0} = \dfrac{1}{2L}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} {f\left( x \right)dx} \\
```

to

```
a_0 &= \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\,dx \\
```

Streamlined code is not just aesthetically pleasing; it is also *a lot easier* to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 4):

It's not difficult to get display style integrals with the help of `drcases` from `mathtools`.

More difficult is to maintain alignment between the equals signs, which is quite important in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[3][c]{%
  \eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$\displaystyle#3$}%
}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \eqmathbox[l]{A}{a_0}
  = \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\diff x \\
& \mathopen{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace} % space adjustment
  \begin{drcases}
  \eqmathbox[l]{A}{a_n}
  = \frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L} f(x)\cos \left( \dfrac{n\pi}{L}x \right)\diff x\\
  \eqmathbox[l]{A}{b_n}
  = \frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L} f(x)\sin \left( \dfrac{n\pi}{L}x \right)\diff x
  \end{drcases}
,\quad n = 1,2,3,\dots,N
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I've made a few adjustments and used `eqparbox` in order to make equally sized boxes for the left-hand sides, with **l**eft alignment.

The argument `{A}` to `\eqmathbox` should be unique for the boxes that you want equally sized. Other similar alignments must use a different string. Any string of alphanumeric characters can be used.

Note `\diff` for the differential, so it is automatically spaced from the previous part, which is common usage in mathematical typography. Instead of `\left` and `\right`, I'd recommend, for this case, `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`: try and spot the tiny, but significant difference.

The `\mathopen{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}` is a dirty trick to avoid misalignment.

Finally, I removed useless braces from your input and also `\{ and` }`around`1,2,\dots,N`, which I've never seen used in this case.

About `\int\limits`, I've strong opinion against it, because it makes for very high and deep lines. If you want *all* integrals to be treated as `\limits`, use the appropriate option to `amsmath`. In general, I'd use `\limits` just for integrals over paths or multiple integrals over some domain.

I show the output with `intlimits` and without it. In the second picture I used `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` in place of `\left` and `\right` to help you in spotting the different spacing mentioned above.

[image]

[image]

Anyway, I endorse Mico's opinion that a single `align*` environment is best, with no big brace.

Comment: I am among the giants of TeX.SE :-). Is drcases in the mathtools manual?

Comment: @Sebastiano Section 3.4.3.

Answer (score 4):

[Perhaps the best option is to avoid the brace altogether](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569112/227987). If you want one, maybe a somewhat more subtle brace could be nicer so that the attention of the reader remains on the more relevant content. Once you consider such options, you can avoid tuning and just work with an `align*` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,fit,tikzmark}
\mleftright
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a_0 &= \dfrac{1}{2L}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} f\left( x \right)\diff x \\
a_n &= \tikzmarknode{A}{\dfrac{1}{L}\int\limits_{-L}^{L} f(x)\cos \left( \dfrac{n\pi}{L}x
 \right)\diff x}\\
b_n &= \tikzmarknode{B}{\dfrac{1}{L}\int\limits_{ - L}^L f(x)\sin \left( \dfrac{n\pi}{L}x 
\right)\diff x}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[fit=(A)(B),inner ysep=0pt](F){};
\draw[thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace}] 
    (F.north east) -- (F.south east)
    node[midway,right=1ex]{$n = \{1,2,3,\dots,N\}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the tikz-based approach to drawing a decoration. To declutter the code somewhat, you could replace all five instances of `\dfrac` with `\frac`. Getting rid of the `\limits` directives would permit a much more compact display of the material; see also [@egreg's comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569120/5001) on the (non-)desirability of `\int\limits` for the equations at hand.

Comment: @Mico I agree with all this. Yet I would not even type the formula like this. In most of the literature the first and second line get combined to something that contains `\frac{1}{(1+\delta_{n0})L}` and one does not need the brace nor the specification of `n` at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't touch :-) the math space `\mkern -247mu` of the code of

```
\[\mkern -247mu a_0 = \frac{1}{2L}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)dx\]
```

you can have (very similar) structure of your initial image. Here I have used `mathtools` + `rcases`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\begin{document}

\[
\mkern -247mu a_0 = \frac{1}{2L}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)dx
\]
\[
\begin{rcases}
{a_n} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{L}\int\limits_{-L}^{L} {f(x)\cos \left({\frac{n\pi}{L}x} \right)dx}\\
{b_n}=\displaystyle \frac{1}{L}\int\limits_{-L}^L {f(x)\sin \left({\frac{n\pi}{L}x} \right)dx}
\end{rcases},
n = \{1,2,3,...,N\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `\mkern -247mu`. :-)

Comment: @Mico I took the ahahahahhah meter to establish the accuracy of the distance.

Comment: Thank you guys... Your answers really helped me out... I tried all and all turned out good for me... Cheers!

Comment: @Sylvester Welcome again in the community :-)